# Checking if UIImageView is animating

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

i am currently working on an application that allows the user to select a profile image.

I am able to select the image and display it on the iPhone screen. I want to make sure that the user has selected an image before saving all his information. I have have done some research around and have found that isAnimating() function can be used to check that the UIImageView is actually "animating"/"displaying" the user's image. Unfortunately, when I do the check

```
        if profileImage.isAnimating() == true{

             self.user.save()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToMainScreen", sender: self)
        } else {
            println("please select an image")
            println(profileImage.isAnimating())
        }
```

Even if profileImage is displaying ... isAnimating() always returns false. :(

I'm not sure if there is something faulty with this function or if we have to do something else.

Any help will be really appreciated. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong method. isAnimating returns YES when a UIImageView is, well, animating. UIImageView allows you to animate between an array of UIImages

see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImageView/isAnimating) for more details.

I think you will want to use the `image` property. If its nil, then no image has been set.

```
    if profileImage.image { // nil evaluates to false
        self.user.save()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToMainScreen", sender: self)
    } else {
        println("please select an image")
        // println(profileImage.isAnimating())
    }
```